# How large does a sample need to be in order to be very representative with high probability?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose we have a set $X$ of $n$ objects that we want to sample uniformly at random. Let $\ell \colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a total, surjective function assigning a label to each object. For a subset $X'$ of $X$ and a label $y \in Y$ let $f_{X'}(y)$ denote the relative frequency of $y$ in $X'$, i.e. $\frac{|\{ x \in X' \mid \ell(x) = y  \}|}{|X'|}$.

Given a subset $X'$ of $X$, there are two simple ways to measure how representative it is:
$$r_0(X') := \min \left\{ r \geq 0 \mid \forall y \in Y \colon (1-r)\cdot f_X(y) \leq f_{X'}(y) \leq (1+r)\cdot f_X(y) \right\}  $$
$$r_1(X') := \min \left\{ r  \geq 0 \mid \forall y \in Y \colon f_X(y) - r \leq f_{X'}(y) \leq f_X(y) + r \right\}  $$
If $r_0(X') = r$, this means the relative frequencies in $X'$ differ by at most $(100\cdot r)$% from their counterparts in $X$. The function $r_1$ refers to the absolute difference. In both cases 0 denotes the highest degree of representativity, i.e. all relative frequencies in $X'$ coincide with their respective ones in $X$.

Assume we only know the number of objects $n$, the number of labels $l =|Y|$ and the least amount of times a certain label occurs $k = \min \left\{ |\ell^{-1}(y)| \mid y \in Y \right\}$. I would like to know the smallest sample size $m=|X'|$ such that the probability that $r_i(X') \leq r$ is at least $p$ for some given $r \geq 0$, $p \in [0,1]$ and $i \in \{1,2\}$. Stated differently, I'm looking for (bounds on) the function $f_i(n,l,k,r,p)=m$.

Comment: Shouldn't it be max in the definition of $r_0$ and $r_1$?

Comment: I think min is correct, since smaller means more representative. If we had max then it would be undefined since if a particular $r$ satisfies the condition then every $r'>r$ does as well. Basically the definition says to look for the smallest intervals in terms of the relative frequencies of $X$ and $r$ that contains the ones of $X'$.